# How does a home router know the upstream address?

Tags: networking, router, isp

I've been recently told that you can change routers easily by simply swapping them. However, I was then confused to how a router knows the upstream IP address of the ISP?

Comment: *I've been recently told that you can change routers easily by simply swapping them.* Sometimes can, sometimes cannot.

Comment: Via [dhcp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have configured the router or cable modem to use the correct virtual circuit, it connects to the remote modem using a form of PPP (often PPPoATM, for example).  Part of that connection process includes assignment of IP addresses in a similar manner to DHCP.  Once the PPP negotiation is complete, both interfaces have an IP address and know the address of the other end.

Once an IP link is established, there might also be a DHCP request, allowing your equipment to obtain addresses of other useful services such as NTP and NNTP servers, for instance.

Comment: Actually, DHCP is not (commonly or perhaps at all) used over PPP. PPP already provides method to inform the client about its configuration (IPCP).